# How to put data in an array based on id?

Tags: python

I have two functions. The  output of the first function is set of data. The template of this data is  two arrays x and y. I displayed data per keys. For that, I have a set of array x and y for every key.

```
key=1
x1= [1549546516, 1549546526, 1549546541, 1549546542, 1549546558, 1549546559, 1549546560, 1549546594, 1549546600, 1549546606]
y1= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

key=2
x1= [1549546515, 1549546547, 1549546578, 1549546590, 1549546596, 1549546598, 1549546604, 1549546621, 1549546623, 1549546626, 1549546648, 1549546685]
y1= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
x2= [1549546607]
y2= [1]
```

I try to append my data by  key. After that I want to loop data per key also and  plot its histogram. I hope it is clear.

Comment: Your code is really unclear.. Did you consider using a dictionary?

Comment: Could you perhaps rephrase or clarify your question? Particularly the first discussion of the keys and relationship to arrays? Do you meant by the `keys=2` example that the second set illustrates 2 sets of keys. Or is that first code block meant to be actual code?

Comment: Also, could you flesh out your question with an [mcve]? For example, you appear to be plotting. With what? matplotlib and scipy aren't included as imports here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I edited my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address the first part of your question, that is, structuring your data, and assuming what I read you to be asking, I'd suggest you take the dict() approach. This will give you a simple interface to your data and its keys, For example:

```
{
    "example1":{
    "x1": [1549546516, 1549546526, 1549546541, 1549546542, 1549546558, 1549546559, 1549546560, 1549546594, 1549546600, 1549546606],
    "y1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]},
    "example2":
    {
    "x1": [1549546515, 1549546547, 1549546578, 1549546590, 1549546596, 1549546598, 1549546604, 1549546621, 1549546623, 1549546626, 1549546648, 1549546685],
    "y1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    "x2": [1549546607],
    "y2": [1]}}
```